# Ruby on Rails, namespace, models and many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces

I'm using namespace, and I have the follow models:

```
class Administradora::Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails, foreign_key: :administradora_owner_id
  has_many :junta_mails, through: :owner_mails
end

class Junta::Mail < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails, class_name: "OwnerMail", foreign_key: :junta_mail_id
  has_many :adminstradora_owners, through: :owner_mails
end

class OwnerMail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :administradora_owner,  :foreign_key => :owner_id, :primary_key => :administradora_owner_id
  belongs_to :junta_mail,  :foreign_key => :mail_id, :primary_key => :mail_id
end
```

In *rails console I* do the following and works fine:

```
Administradora::Owner.first.owner_mails
Junta::Mail.find(4).owner_mails
```

But if I try:

```
x = OwnerMail.create(administradora_owner_id: 4,junta_mail_id: 3, created_at: "2016/04/04", updated_at: "2016/04/04")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Administradora owner
>   must exist, Junta mail must exist

Ids `3`, `4` do exist in their tables.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is your Rails version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to specify the class_name on the belongs_to method. 
Like this:

```
belongs_to :administradora_owner, class_name: 'Administrator::Owner'  ....
```